# How to get data from factory and send it in headers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing web application in angularjs. I am making lot of http calls to interact with web api. As a result i have to send lot of data in headers too. I have created factory for get data as below. These data should should be passed in headers. Below is my factory.

```
var myapp = angular.module('RoslpApp');

    myapp.factory("ScrollFunction", ['$location', '$anchorScroll', '$cookieStore', function ($location, $anchorScroll, $cookieStore) {
        return {
            getheaders: function () {
                var cookiePreferredLanguage = $cookieStore.get('PreferredLanguage');
                var headers={
                    Logintoken: $cookieStore.get('LoginToken'),
                    LoginId: $cookieStore.get('LoginID'),
                    RequestedPlatform: "Web",
                    RequestedLanguage: cookiePreferredLanguage
                };
                return headers;
            }
        }
    }

        ]);
    Below is my sample http call.

     function getpermissiondetails() {
                var headersdata = ScrollFunction.getheaders();
                $scope.Create = "Create";
                var getsavedvechilceUrl = baseurl + "api/RolesPermission/getgroups";
                var request = {
                    url: getsavedvechilceUrl,
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        RequestedPlatform: headersdata.RequestedPlatform,
                        RequestedLanguage: headersdata.RequestedLanguage,
                        Logintoken: headersdata.LoginToken,
                        LoginId: headersdata.LoginID
                    }
                };
                $http(request).then(function (response) {
                    $scope.groups = response.data.data;
                }, function (error) {
                })
            }
```

What i want in header is i already have data in    var headersdata = ScrollFunction.getheaders(); Is it possible to pass something like  headers: { headersdata  } because i can make add headers in factory. No need to expand it in each http call. I tried headers: { headersdata  } but this is not sending any data to api. May i know is there any better solution? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I suppose what you got up there is a working solution and you are just looking for advice to refractor your code?

Comment: That is working solution. I want something     var headers={ factory data}. Now i am assigning each properties like  RequestedPlatform: headersdata.RequestedPlatform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is a code refractoring question.

**Q:** Can I avoid doing the messy property assignment by doing something shortcut like `headers={ factory data }`?

**A:** Ok. I probably did a bad job paraphrasing your question. I'm just trying to make it more understandable.

**Short answer: Yes**. You can further shorten your code by doing this.

```
var request = {
    url: getsavedvechilceUrl,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: ScrollFunction.getheaders()
};
```

**Why?**

Your function `getheaders()` is already returning a javascript object which is exactly what `request.headers` is looking. An object {}.

Since `getHeaders()` is already returning an object you can just plug it straight into `request.headers`. That is, you no need to re-create an object and reassign the property back in one by one.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes this is what i need. I am bad in phrasing questions.